# Loading NOSQL data into Spark nodes

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to understand what happens when I load data into Spark from a NoSQL source. ie. Will it try to load the records into the driver  and then distribute it to the worker nodes OR will it load records into all the worker nodes simultaneously? . Basically is there any way to load data in parallel if yes, how to ensure the same record is not processed by more than one node?
If it is not a parallel process would writing the same json into a ".json" file help?(provided each line is a record)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will always load directly to the workers.  Depending on the source of the data and how it is stored, it can be possible to be loaded in parallel.  When the data is being loaded, the data will be sharded with non-overlapping rows, so you won't have to worry about processing the same data twice.  The file format will be irrelevant.  Which data source are you loading from (mongo, cassandra, hbase)?  I can give a better answer if you tell me the source system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Joe. I am trying to load it from Cloudant...Any insights on this would be very helpful.